# Python win32com outlook attach file with "insert as text" method

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to send a HTML webpage via outlook with python win32com.
However, I don't know how to config the add attachment call to do "insert as text" method.

Does anyone know how to do that?

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch, constants
const=win32com.client.constants

olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "I AM SUBJECT!!"
newMail.Body = "I AM IN THE BODY\nSO AM I!!!"
newMail.To = "abc@abc.com"
attachment1 = "x:\\report.htm"

newMail.Attachments.Add(Source=attachment1)
newMail.display()
newMail.Send()
```

thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like you're missing some arguments on the `Attachments.Add()` call judging from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862085.aspx) example.

Comment: From MSDN site, the method parameter includes (Source, Type, Position, DisplayName) only. I don't see parameter relative to set "Insert as Text" function.

Comment: Yes, same as what my link says...but you're only passing one argument in your code.

Answer (score 7):

you can use this

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch, constants
const=win32com.client.constants

olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "I AM SUBJECT!!"

newMail.To = "abc@abc.com"
attachment1 = "x:\\report.htm"

with open(attachment1 , 'r') as myfile:
   data=myfile.read()

newMail.Body = "Please Find the Report here " + data

newMail.HTMLBody = "I AM IN THE BODY\nSO AM I!!!" + data
newMail.Attachments.Add(Source=attachment1)
newMail.display()
newMail.Send()
```

you may need to convert the html file to string first and concatenate with mail.body

Comment: let me know if this helped you :)